# SQL to find players who play one game

Tags: sql

Given

```
create table account (
  id int not null,
  name varchar(100),
  country varchar(100),
  primary key (id)
  );

create table score (
  id int not null,
  game_name varchar(100),
  score int
  );
```

How do I find accounts who played only one game please?
account.id should match score.id. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some example data ? or what you have tried ? by the way how youll know how many time they played ? is there a table or column explain that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, then you look for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM account
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM score
             GROUP BY id
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```